# Need help better understanding UIStackView

Tags: ios, xcode, uistackview

I watched through this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O0llR7sfrkc) to learn about `UIStackView` but I'm still having trouble. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3ATI.png) is what I'm working with right now. The bottom half (which is partly covered by the date picker) is what I'm looking to achieve.

Three horizontal views in one row and three vertical views below it. As you can see from my stackview hierarchy, the white background view and orange background view are in a vertical stack. I didn't touch the view with a white background to show the contrast of what is happening.

- Months, days, weeks are in a horizontal stack.
- Seconds, minutes, hours are in a vertical stack.
- Then those two stacks are in a vertical stack.

That vertical stack is pinned 20 pixels in every direction.

I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quite difficult to give you a definitive answer without being able to see every constraint and stack view setting, but here are a few pointers that might get you somewhere:

- Your seconds, minutes and hours stack view has three horizontal stack views in it that each only contain one 'card view'. These stack views aren't doing anything so I would suggest simplifying this to just three card views in a vertical stack view.
- You stack view may well not be pinned to what you think it is. The appearance in the simulator would suggest that it is not pinned to the view that it sits inside. Alternatively, that view may not be pinned to the top level view correctly.
- Once the above is sorted, you may need to look into the stack view settings, I suspect that your vertical and horizontal stack views at the lowest level should both be set to fill equally, which may not be the case at the moment.
- The other thing to check is that you don't have constraints that are conflicting with each other. If you are putting things in stack views which already have defined heights, widths, aspect ratios, etc then this can interfere with the stack views doing their magic.
- Finally if all else fails, throw all your stack views and constraints away and rebuild them using the smallest number of each that you can. Stack views first, followed by stack view settings, then constraints only where you need them.

Generally speaking, I would advice against using the 'iPhone shaped' view controllers in interface builder, they tend to hide issues that will occur at runtime or on different sized devices and give a false sense of security. The generic, square views are a better bet. Finally, don't give up, everyone who has managed to master stack views has looked at a screen like this and held their head in their hands in despair at some point!